# Sahi OS Controller doesn't open with Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 m

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, sahi

I have updated my chrome to Version 24.0.1312.52 m. Sahi OS controller doesn't open with the updated Chrome. I have checked the same with Alt, Alt+Ctrl, turned off popup blocker but still no luck. I checked the same on another machine and the same issue happened i.e. sahi controller doesn't open after updating chrome to the latest version.

OS: Windows 7 Pro

Browser: Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 m

Sahi: Sahi OS version

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Looking into possible fix.

Comment: Go to http://sahi.co.in/w/help-the-sahi-controller-does-not-come-up and read for details

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on, but here is the workaround.

Open sahi/htdocs/spr/concat.js

Look for `Sahi.prototype.openControllerWindow`.
Replace the full function so that it looks like:

```
Sahi.prototype.openControllerWindow = function (e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (!this.isHotKeyPressed(e)) return true;
    if (this._isChrome()) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){_sahi.topSahi().openWin(e)}, 100);
    } else {
        this.topSahi().openWin(e);
    }
    return true;
};
```

Next search for `_sahiControl` in the same file and replace it with `sahiControl`. (You should see 2 occurrences.)

Restart Sahi, clear browser cache and check.

Regards,
Narayan

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Sahi 4.5.1. You can download it from this link: http://sahi.co.in/downloads-archive/

Thanks,